# Turtle cannot select path to destination in GIS generated network unless duplicate and unconnected nodes are removed

Tags: netlogo

I have been trying to work out how to make a turtle move from one node to another in a network based on a GIS road map. The issue is that the turtle cannot set a path using `nw:turtles-on-path-to` unless I remove node duplicates and nodes that are not connected (the relevant block of code I used is from someone else's model). Below is the code that works when I remove duplicates and unconnected nodes:

```
    foreach gis:feature-list-of roads-dataset [ vector-feature ->
    foreach  gis:vertex-lists-of vector-feature [ vertex ->
      let previous-turtle nobody
      let first-turtle nobody
      foreach vertex [point ->
        let location gis:location-of point
        if not empty? location
        [ 
          create-nodes 1
          [ set myneighbours n-of 0 turtles
            set xcor item 0 location
            set ycor item 1 location
            set road-type gis:property-value vector-feature "Classification"
            ;set shape "circle"
            ;set size 0.5
            ifelse previous-turtle = nobody
            [ set first-turtle self ]
            [ create-link-with previous-turtle ]
            set hidden? true
            set previous-turtle self ]
        ]
      ]
    ] ]

    delete-duplicates
    ask nodes [ set myneighbours link-neighbors ]

    delete-not-connected
    ask nodes [ set myneighbours link-neighbors ]

    to delete-duplicates
      ask nodes [
        if count nodes-here with [ description = "road" ] > 1[
          ask other nodes-here with [ description = "road" ][

            ask myself [create-links-with other [link-neighbors] of myself]
            die]
        ]
        ]
    end   

    to delete-not-connected
       ask nodes [set test 0]
       ask one-of nodes [set test 1]
         repeat 500 [
           ask nodes with [test = 1]
           [ask myneighbours [set test 1]]]
       ask nodes with [test = 0][die]
    end

    to go
      ask person [
        if destination = 0 [ create-link select-destination ]
        if mypath = 0 [ select-path ]
        if mypath != 0 [ move ]
      ]
      tick
    end

    to create-link
      create-link-with min-one-of nodes [ distance myself ]
      ask links [ set hidden? true ]
    end

    to select-destination
      set destination one-of nodes with [ road-type = "main road" ]
    end

    to select-path
      set mypath nw:turtles-on-path-to destination
    end

    to move
     ifelse length mypath > 0
     [ move-to item 0 mypath set mypath remove-item 0 mypath ]
     [ stop ]
    end
```

This code works perfectly fine. However, the road network gets distorted after deleting duplicate and unconnected nodes - the road networks does not have the same appearance as the original one. The only way the turtle can move along the network is by keeping the code in the format above. If I exclude `delete-duplicates`and `delete-not-connected` then `mypath` returns false.

I there a way I can keep the appearance of the original network and at the same allow the turtle to set a path and move along it to reach the destination? What would be the issue that does not allow the turtle to set a path unless `delete-duplicates`and `delete-not-connected` are used?

Your support is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `delete-duplicates` is necessary? My guess is that the reason `delete-not-connected` is necessary is because, without it, `select-destination` can select a node that is not reachable by the turtle. I'll get to how to fix this in a moment. First, there are a few problems with your code that we should discuss.

First, you have turtles create a link between them and their current location. This is a little weird, because it's essentially saying that this turtle is a road on the road network, which doesn't make sense. Practically, this gets weird if and when you want the turtles to select new destinations. They'll still be linked with the node they started on! This would allow them "teleport" around the network. Not good! Instead, I suggest creating a turtle variable called `current-location`, which tracks the node that the turtle is on.

So, `create-link` should be turned into

```
to set-location
  set current-location min-one-of nodes [ distance myself ]
end
```

`move` then becomes (I deleted the `stop` from your code because it's unnecessary):

```
to move
  if not empty? mypath [
    set current-location first mypath
    move-to current-location
    set mypath but-first mypath
  ]
end
```

and `select-path` becomes:

```
to select-path
  set mypath [ nw:turtles-on-path-to destination ] of current-location
end
```

Actually, we can simplify this further. Because the turtle is keeping track of its current location, you don't need to keep track of the path yourself anymore. Instead, delete `mypath` and `select-path` and change `move` to:

```
to move
  if current-location != destination [
    let next-node first [ nw:turtles-on-path-to destination ] of current-location
    set current-location next-node
    move-to current-location
  ]
end
```

and change `go` to:

```
to go
  ask person [
    if destination = 0 [
      set-location
      select-destination
    ]
    move
  ]
  tick
end
```

Much simpler! Note that this should still be fast as `nw` remembers the shortest path between nodes. If you have a really big network or something, you can still keep track of the path yourself if you want, but I'd try this first.

Okay, now we're ready to fix the disconnected nodes problem without deleting anything in the network. Basically, `select-destination` should only choose a destination that the turtle can get to. That looks like this:

(Edit: This code is incorrect. See below)

```
to select-destination
  set destination one-of nodes with [
    road-type = "main road" and
    is-number? [ nw:distance-to [current-location] of myself ] of myself 
  ]
end
```

The `[ nw:distance-to myself ] of myself` in there will get the distance from the current-location (which is what the first `myself` refers to) to the potential destination (which is what the second `myself` refers to). `nw:distance-to` will return a number (the distance) if the target node is reachable from the source node; otherwise it returns `false`. So `is-number?` checks to make sure it actually gave us a number back.

Hopefully this helps solve your problem while also simplifying your code. The duplicates thing really shouldn't matter. If it does, either reply with a comment or edit your question, and I'll take a look.

Edit:

Thanks for uploading your model and data! I realized I actually messed up the `select-destination` procedure. It should be:

```
to select-destination
  set destination one-of [ nodes with [
    road-type = "road" and
    is-number? [ nw:distance-to myself ] of myself
  ] ] of current-location
end
```

That is, the person was supposed to be querying the `current-location` for a reachable road. Obviously, since the person is not connected to the network, they can't get a reachable road directly.

Next, it looks like a significant problem is actually the data is extremely disconnected. The network that you're creating contains 5619 disconnected components which each only contain 3-5 nodes. So it's no wonder that the turtle can't find a destination it can reach!

I think you may be interpreting the data incorrectly. I would expect that the various the nodes created from different feature lists should be connected somehow, but you're not doing that (which is why you end up with so many disconnected components). Unfortunately, this is where we hit the limit of my knowledge; I don't know much about GIS. I remember one of my colleagues that was working on a similar project had to do something like merging vertices that were on top of each other.  This would turns the network generation code into the following:

```
  foreach gis:feature-list-of roads-dataset [ vector-feature ->
    foreach  gis:vertex-lists-of vector-feature [ vertex ->
      let previous-turtle nobody
      foreach vertex [point ->
        let location gis:location-of point
        if not empty? location
        [
          let x item 0 location
          let y item 1 location
          let current-node one-of (turtles-on patch x y) with [ xcor = x and ycor = y ]
          if current-node = nobody [
            create-nodes 1 [
              setxy x y
              set shape "circle"
              set size 0.5
              set road-type "road"
              set hidden? true
              set current-node self
            ]
          ]
          ask current-node [
            if is-turtle? previous-turtle [
              create-link-with previous-turtle
            ]
            set previous-turtle self
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

This appears to behave correctly. (I also cleaned up a few things that we're doing anything) That is, it looks to see if there's already a node at that *exact* location, and connects to that one if so, otherwise it creates a new node.

Here's the full updated code: https://gist.github.com/qiemem/b59f3657bea34b9aa67648760b9c7471

I also tweaked a few other things: The person now sets their location in `setup`, which makes sense: their location should update correctly after that. I added `tick` to the end of `go`, which all models should have. You might want to change view updates to "on ticks". Finally, I made the person choose a new location upon getting to their destination for testing. You might want to make `go` a forever button now; you'll the person going from place to place.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Bryan! I have made the changes accordingly, however, I now get an error called "Extension exception: Expected this input to be an agent but got the number 0 instead" (the destination is set to nobody). The error highlights that `nw:turtles-on-path-to` returns no path to destination. Also, I removed both procedures `delete-duplicates` and `delete-not-connected` because using these changed the layout of the original network.

Comment: Hmm, is one of the turtles on a node that isn't connected with any "main road"?

Comment: I only created one `person` (for simplicity purposes) who is on the node selected by the `set-location` procedure. What I do not understand is why the block of code I first posted works and allows the turtle to move to its destination, although it is not written in a good format and it also distorts the appearance of the network. What would you recommend I should check/ do?

Comment: Would you post your full code? Also, is the GIS data shareable? If so, could you link to it?

Comment: I uploaded the netlogo file and map files on google drive - you can access them at this [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5ReYaf_vfpqNUd6cjVLdTk5YTA?usp=sharing) . I hope you would be able to find a way to make that turtle move to anyone of the nodes on the network.

Comment: I updated my answer with a description of what was going on and the fixes. Hope that helps!

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! I included your fix into my entire model and it now works as expected.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Make sure to mark the answer correct so other's know this question has been successfully answered.